# Proof of "If $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$, then f is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$."

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am having trouble understanding the proof of theorem $19.2$ in "Elementary Analysis-The Theory Of Calculus" By Kenneth A. Ross, here it is:

[image]

I don't understand the purpose of replacing $\delta$ with $\frac{1}{n}$, I know that it is mathematically correct since $\frac{1}{n}>0$ when $n>0$ but I can't see how this added any value to the proof.

The second question, does $\lim_{k\Rightarrow \infty} y_{n_k}=x_0$ stem from the fact that $|x_n-y_n|<\delta$ which implies they are convergent to the same limit, hence all their subsequences converge to this same limit as well?

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: 1) Because you want to use Bolzano-Weirstrass, and thus you need to build a sequence $(x_n)_{\color{red}{n\in\mathbb N}}$ s.t.... 2) It comes from the fact that $x_n\to x_0$ and $|x_n-y_n|\leq \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @Shaun do you mean not to post pictures of texts in questions or not to take them as true? If it is the later, I did the screenshot myself

Comment: @Surb so 2 is as I said? and about $1$, I didn't really get it, as long as we have a bounded sequence we can use the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, how is this building a sequence?

Comment: 2) No it's not. 1) For all $n\in \mathbb N$, there is $x_n,y_n\in (a,b)$ s.t. ..... this mean that whenever you fix a $n$, you take an $x_n\in [a,b]$ and a $y_n\in [a,b]$ s.t.... So at the end, you built sequences $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ that are in $[a,b]$ and that have some properties... in particular, there are bounded.

Comment: I mean not to post pictures of text. They're not user friendly and cannot be searched.

Comment: Type it up. ${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand the purpose of replacing $\delta$ with $\frac{1}{n}$

This is needed to move from statements about any positive real $\delta$ to get sequences. We take the sentence "For each $\delta > 0$ ..." and plug in $\delta = 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}$ to show that the sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ with property $|x_n - y_n| < \frac{1}{n}$ exist. Leaving it as $\delta$, we would have no relation to the sequence index, and having differences smaller than any constant $\delta$ doesn't make the difference converge.

> Does $\lim_{k \to \infty} y_{n_k} = x_0$ stem from the fact that $|x_n-y_n| < \delta$ which implies they are convergent to the same limit, hence all their subsequences converge to this same limit as well?

Almost. But again, $|x_n - y_n| < \delta$ doesn't describe convergence; we need the difference to get smaller as a function of $n$, which is true in $|x_n-y_n| < \frac{1}{n}$.

To be more complete about it, the convergence of $\{x_{n_k}\}$ means that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k>K$ implies $|x_{n_k} - x_0| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. So whenever $k$ is large enough that $k > K$ and $n_k > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$ then by the triangle inequality,

$$ |y_{n_k} - x_0| \leq |y_{n_k} - x_{n_k}| + |x_{n_k} - x_0| < \frac{1}{2/\epsilon} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon $$

which shows $\lim_{k \to \infty} y_{n_k} = x_0$.